# Is mongoose.Types.ObjectId() an absolutely Node.js client-side operation?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using the Mongoose next to the Node.js. The question is:

Does the following command for creation of the ObjectID value make a call to the server?

```
mongoose.Types.ObjectId()
```

I've checked my local MongoDB server log, and it doesn't show anything like a call to the single local MongoDB node/server for requesting a new ObjectID value. However, I'm not sure if the default server log is about all the operations(trivial and essential ops), or not!

NOTE: trivial ops here means the non-manipulative data operations!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple script suggests that it does not make a call to the server:
Installing mongoose by running `npm install mongoose`

Then make a 2-liner index.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
console.log(new mongoose.Types.ObjectId);
```

Because we haven't even connected yet.